# How to send int over the socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm learning very basic socket programming with C++
I'm stuck at the part where I'm trying to send a randomly generated int
over the socket.

server.cpp

```
int code = rand();
send(connfd, (char*)code, sizeof(int), 0);
```

client.cpp

```
int code = 0;
recv(connfd, (char*)code, sizeof(int), 0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What the compiler says?

Comment: C++? Why would you tag C then?

Comment: `code` isn't an  address and not even will become an address by casting it to an address type, a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 5):

For starters:

1. You are not checking the return value from either of your calls. sockets are notorious (by nature) error prone.
2. Assuming all bytes will be sent and received together - but TCP is prone to segmentation, fragmentation, partial sends, and all sorts of stuff where you should never assume you'll receive everything sent in one call.  Which makes it even more important to check the return value!
3. That cast you do: `(char*)code` is incorrect.  More appropriate to do `(char*)&code`, but it doesn't recognize partial receives.

Assuming you are using a TCP socket:

Send:

```
int data = rand();
char* tosend = (char*)&data;
int remaining = sizeof(data);
int result = 0;
int sent = 0;
while (remaining > 0) {
    result = send(connfd, tosend+sent, remaining, 0);
    if (result > 0) {
        remaining -= result;
        sent += result;
    }
    else if (result < 0) {
        printf("ERROR!\n");
        // probably a good idea to close socket
        break;
    }
}
```

Receive:

```
int value = 0;
char* recv_buffer = (char*)&value;
int remaining = sizeof(int);
int received = 0
int result = 0;
while (remaining > 0) {
    result = recv(connfd, recv_buffer+received, remaining, 0);
    if (result > 0) {
        remaining -= result;
        received += result;
    }
    else if (result == 0) {
        printf("Remote side closed his end of the connection before all data was received\n");
        // probably a good idea to close socket
        break;
    }
    else if (result < 0) {
        printf("ERROR!\n");
        // probably a good idea to close socket
        break;
    }
}
```

For a UDP socket, some of the principals remaining the same with regards to error checking, casting to/from memory buffers.  But with UDP you should not do the "looping" thing since UDP is a datagram protocol.

Comment: @Galik: Just replace `char buffer[sizeof(int)] = {0};
char* recv_buffer = buffer;` by `char* recv_buffer = (char*) &value;` And drop this `value = *(int*)buffer;`.

Comment: @Galik - yes. Typo. Fixed.

Comment: @Galik - I understand the aliasing (alignment) thing.  And you are correct.  This is safe on x86 and most compilers will align the stack variables to be on integer address boundaries.  I'll change it to be a memcpy to be correct.

Comment: @selbie I think alignment is only part of the problem with aliasing. The other part is optimizations. From what I understand the compiler's optimizer always assumes that different types do not alias one another. This can cause UB if they do. That's why you always have to use a `char` to alias other types and not the other way around.

Comment: @Galik - compilers are **much smarter** these days than they used to be with regards to optimizations. The compiler should be able to infer that it can do a fast copy since the source/dest addresses are variables on the stack and have proper alignment. In any case, there's only a few scenarios where writing code that takes such alignments into account is an actual optimization (e.g. games and router devices with blinking lights).

Comment: @alk - I took you original suggestion. Don't know why I didn't consider that before.

Comment: For the code around send, it should be sent += result, right?

Comment: @sherminator35 - correct. And I updated the code after I saw your comment. I just forgot to comment back to you until now.